# Getting xml tags which is present as column value in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a column which is of datatype varchar2. This is very huge table

My task is to scan a particular column which has any xml tags that is present as column value.

since this is a varchar column(I cannot use " extractvalue") is there is possible way to check via query

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt; and the expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 0):

#### Valid XML Data

Assuming that your column only contains valid XML then you can get the names of the tags using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '//*'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.value)
         COLUMNS
           tagname VARCHAR2(200) PATH './name()'
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  id    NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  value VARCHAR2(4000)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
SELECT '<root><a /><b><c /></b></root>' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '<d><e><f /></e></d>' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | VALUE | TAGNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | <root><a /><b><c /></b></root> | root |
| 1 | <root><a /><b><c /></b></root> | a |
| 1 | <root><a /><b><c /></b></root> | b |
| 1 | <root><a /><b><c /></b></root> | c |
| 2 | <d><e><f /></e></d> | d |
| 2 | <d><e><f /></e></d> | e |
| 2 | <d><e><f /></e></d> | f |

If you want a specific tag then:

```sql
SELECT id,
       value, 
       XMLQUERY('//b' PASSING XMLTYPE(t.value) RETURNING CONTENT) AS b
FROM   table_name t
```

Which outputs:

| ID | VALUE | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | <root><a /><b><c /></b></root> | <b><c/></b> |
| 2 | <d><e><f /></e></d> | *null* |

If you just want to know if a tag exists then use `XMLEXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  XMLEXISTS('//b' PASSING XMLTYPE(t.value))
```

Which outputs:

| ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | <root><a /><b><c /></b></root> |

#### Mixed Data

If your column contains a mix of XML and non-XML data then create a user-defined function to try to convert the value to XML and consume any exceptions when the data is not valid XML.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION to_xmltype(
  i_value IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN XMLTYPE
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN XMLTYPE(i_value);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

Then use the queries above replacing `XMLVALUE(t.value)` with `to_xmltype(t.value)` so that the function is called rather than directly calling the object constructor. See the fiddle below for examples.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NSoqEdmH)

Comment: Thanks @MT0 what will be the case if my column value dosent have valid xml format
since I am not sure how the xml tags are stored

Comment: @Arun Updated with a solution for mixed XML and non-XML data.